# Amazon-MWS: Difference between Reports and Order lists

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm trying to integrate the orders from Amazon Marketplace into our system. I did that before with Magento and thought this should be easy as that, but somehow I got stuck.

I downloaded the Java APIs from [Amazon](https://developer.amazonservices.com/index.html) and started playing around with the examples.
So far so good - I was able to get them running. 
But playing with the [Reports API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/192-9087225-9522840?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=reports&version=latest) and the [Orders API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/192-9087225-9522840?ie=UTF8&group=orders&section=orders&version=latest), I started to wonder which one to use if I only want to get the unshipped orders to put them into our system.
1. doing this with the Report API seems very complicated and involves a lot of calls to the MWS. This is documented by Amazon [here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_Overview.html).
2. using the Orders API seems pretty straightforward. I only have to create a `ListOrdersRequest`, define what type of orders I want to have and finally get them via a `ListOrders` call.
So my question is: **What is the reason to choose the Reports API over the Orders API?**

Seems like Amazon is recommending the Reports API, but I really do not understand why this should be so complicated. Why should I get Reports when I can get the Orders directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both approaches can work. Here's why I would pick the Reports API:

- Reports are more scalable. I believe MWS reports can return an unlimited number of records. `ListOrders` can only return a maximum of 100 orders. You can get more using `ListOrdersByNextToken`, but that brings throttling into the problem and it is not clear whether or not you're just paging by an offset (which could cause lost/duplicate orders) or whether it is a snapshot.
- You can acknowledge reports and filter on unacknowledged reports. Orders can be acknowledged too, but I don't think there is a way of filtering ListOrders based on acknowledgement status.
- Reports can be scheduled to auto-generate on an interval, as often as every 15 minutes. This means that it may not be as many calls as you think: really, it's only three every interval: one to list unacknowledged order reports, one to pull the report you want and one to acknowledge it.